# Derivative inequality problem

Tags: real-analysis

Trying to solve the following problem:

---

Let $f : (a, b) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable, and assume that
$$\left | f'(x) - f'(y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |$$
for all $x, y \in (a, b)$. Show that
$$\left | f(x) - f(y) - f'(x)(x - y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |^{2}$$
for all $x, y \in (a, b)$.

(Hint: Consider $\varphi(t) = f(y + t(x - y))$ for $0 \leq t \leq 1$.)

---

The inequalities reminded me of one of theorems in Mean Value Theorem chapter:

---

**Theorem**: If $f$ is a real continuous function on $[a, b]$ which is differentiable in $(a, b)$, then there is a point $x \in (a, b)$ at which
$$f(b) - f(a) = (b - a)f'(x)$$

---

So, if $x$ was in $[a, b]$ in the theorem, which is not, we could do

$$\left | f(x) - f(y) - f'(x)(x - y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |^{2}$$
$$\left | f'(y)(x - y) - f'(x)(x - y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |^{2}$$
$$\left |x - y \right | \left | f'(y) - f'(x) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |^{2}$$
$$\left | f'(y) - f'(x) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |$$
$$\left | f'(x) - f'(y) \right | \leq \left | x - y \right |$$

But since it's not, we can't apply the theorem and solve it that way.

The hint seems to suggest to use the definition of a derivative, with $\varphi(t) = f(y + t(x - y))$, where $0 \leq t \leq 1$, but I have no idea where does $0 \leq t \leq 1$ come from and how to even apply it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some $c \in [x,y]$, 
$$
\begin{align}
|f(x)-f(y)-f'(x)(x-y)| &= | f'(c)(x-y)-f'(x)(x-y)| = |f'(c)-f'(x)| \times |x-y| \\
&\leq |c-x| |x-y| \leq |x-y|^2
\end{align}
$$
because $|c-x|$ is maximized by $c=y$, the point of $[x,y]$ which lies farthest from $x$.

Comment: Except that you need $c \in (x, y)$ to apply the theorem. Wouldn't that make the left hand side then strictly $\lt |x - y|^2$, if $c$ can't equal to $y$?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the point. Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: Edited the comment, had a little typo: $x$ instead of $c$. Anyway, I will rephrase. You replaced $f(x)-f(y)$ with $f'(c)(x-y)$ by applying the theorem I mentioned, right? If so, the theorem requires $c \in (x,y)$, not $c \in [x,y]$, and since $c$ can't be equal to $y$, then $|c-x| |x-y|$ is strictly $\lt |x-y|^2$, isn't it?

Comment: But your inequality allows $x=y$, so it can't be strict.